# I am running a julia script on a hpc cluster and getting an error when I use --heap-size-hint

Tags: julia, heap-size

I am new to Julia and this is my first post here,

```
398188] signal (15): Terminated
  in expression starting at /user1/jay.pandey/start_again_copy/start_again/dup_for_check/writing_to_disk.jl:8
  _ZNK4llvm19TargetTransformInfo22getArithmeticInstrCostEjPNS_4TypeENS0_14TargetCostKindENS0_16OperandValueKindES4_NS0_22OperandValuePropertiesES5_NS_8ArrayRefIPKNS_5ValueEEEPKNS_11    InstructionE at /user1/jay.pandey/julia-1.9.0/bin/../lib/julia/libLLVM-14jl.so (unknown line)
  unknown function (ip: 0x4cd832f)
  unknown function (ip: (nil))
  Allocations: 66045750 (Pool: 65995465; Big: 50285); GC: 115
```

This is the error message I get. Could anyone please point out why this happens?

Btw at line 8 I start a let-end block, so tracking the error from here is not easy for me.

I was just trying to use the `--heap-size-hint`  command to limit my ram usage. I had set it to 54 GB and had allocated 60 GB for my job in the cluster. Without the `--heap-size-hint`  command my code used to run fine.
Someone please help!

Comment: That's a hard error to get for a new Julia user. That indicates that the crash is in LLVM, which is dark compiler magic territory. Can you provide output of `versioninfo()` on this system?